# How do I skip tutorials?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

In GTA San Andreas for iOS, you can skip some cutscenes by pressing the arrow at the top right of the screen. But when the game is explaining something to you, it takes a long time to move on. Is there any way to skip these, because there isn't a arrow on the top right to help me.

Comment: Is that the tablet version? If yes, point it out please.

Comment: In the PC and PS2 versions you cannot skip. I'm pretty sure that you can't in the iOS version either, but, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean the Tutorial when you die and go to the Hospital for the first time for example.

Sadly those kinds of Tutorials **can not be skipped**...